# Convert double to mpf_class precisely

Tags: c++, gmp

What is the correct way to initialize GMP floating point variables (mpf_t or mpf_class, does not matter) from double?

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

int main()
{
        double d=0.1;

        //1024 bits is more that 300 decimal digits
        mpf_set_default_prec(1024);

        mpf_class m(d);

        //after initializing mpf_class variable, set default output precision
        std::cout.precision(50);
        std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::scientific);

        std::cout << m << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
1.00000000000000005551115123125782702118158340454102e-01
```

It would be okay, if I printed `d` directly, but in the `m` variable 300 decimal digits of mantissa are trusted! I use GMP for an iterative numerical method, so these non-zeros introduce mistake and make the method converge slowly.

If I initilize `m` as `mpf_class m("0.1");`, the output is:

```
1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e-01
```

So the problem is not in `operator<<` overload for `mpf_class`. The problem exists not only for initializing, but for assigning too.

At present I use the following:

```cpp
mpf_class linsys::DtoGMP(const double& arg)
{
        char buf[512];
        sprintf(buf,"%.15le\n",arg);
        return mpf_class(buf);
}
```

for correct conversion.

Is there a faster and/or more native way to do it?

My OS is OpenSUSE 12.1, compiler: gcc 4.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print out the double with that same precision, you should see the same strange-looking number. That's simply because [0.1 can't be accurately represented in floating point](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/). The mpf_class is accurately reproducing the value stored in the double. It's the double that isn't matching your expectations.

There's probably a way to specify a precision to gmp or some way to round the input. <s>I'm not sure where to look though</s>.

**Edit**

`mpf_class` has a constructor with a precision parameter: http://www.gnu.org/software/gmp/manual/html_node/C---Interface-Floats.html

Comment: That's understandable. But I have lots of casts from double to GMP with `DtoGMP` function. I think, it's not the fastest variant.

Comment: This constructor is not suitable for me because mantissa is stored into array of long ints, so precision cannot become less than 64 bits (sizeof long int in bits). Even if I set precision to 1, the actual precision will be 64, so about 4 wrong digits will be added to mpf_class variable.

Answer (score -1):

You may use this method

`mpf_class a;
double d=0.1;
a=static_cast<mpf_class>(d*10)/static_cast<mpf_class>(10);`

this method can be used if you know how many decimal places a double has